# How to get the id that pass from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Please kindly help me :)

I have a form like this
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgyyQ.png

and this is code for the form above

input_espenses.php

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 control-label">Jenis pengeluaran</label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <select name="type" id="type" onchange="showPrice(this.value)" required>
  <option value=""></option>
         <?php
                include ('../connector.php');
                
                $query="SELECT * FROM tabel_equipment WHERE sign=0";
                
                $hasil=mysql_query($query, $id_mysql);
                
                while ($record=mysql_fetch_row($hasil))
                {
                    $ID= $record[0];
                    $equipment=$record[1];
                    $price=$record[3];
                    echo "<option value=\"$record[0]\">$record[1]</option>";
                }
            ?>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 control-label">Harga Satuan</label>
 <div class="col-md-4" id="txtHint" class="tip-right form-control input-sm"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Pilih jenis pengeluaran" readonly="">
 </div> 
</div>
   
<div class="form-group">
<label for="" class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 control-label">Jumlah</label>
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <input type='text' id="banyak" name="amount" onkeyup="hitung2(getElementById('txtHint').value,this.value)" title="Masukkan jumlah" class="tip-right form-control input-sm" required/>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="" class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 control-label">Total</label>
 <div class="col-md-4" id="total">
  <input type='text' title="Masukkan total biaya" class="tip-right form-control input-sm" readonly/>
 </div>
</div>
```

and this is the code for get the value inside "Harga Satuan" that i get from my database (i use ajax to get the value)

price.js

```js
function showPrice(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../pages/getprice.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

getprice.php

```html
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

include ('../connector.php');

$query="SELECT * FROM tabel_equipment WHERE ID = '".$q."'";                                            
$hasil=mysql_query($query, $id_mysql);

while ($record=mysql_fetch_row($hasil))
{
    $ID= $record[0];
    $equipment=$record[1];
    $price=$record[3]; ?>
     <input type="text" class="" name="satuan" id="txtHint" value="<?=$price?>" readonly>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Back to the form https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgyyQ.png

**My problem is how to get the id from "Harga Satuan" (id=txtHint) so i can multiple it with the value that user input in "Jumlah" and show the result in "Total"**

this my script to multiple it

totaleq.js

```js
function hitung2(txtHint,banyak){

    var sum = eval(txtHint) * eval(banyak);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;

};
```

Comment: in the form input_expenses.php and totaleq.js, i can't get the id=txtHint from the form so i can calculate it in totaleq.js

Comment: var InputValue= document.forms["YourFormId"]["YourInputName"].value; to get input value in a form and assign it into var inputValue, of course manipulate it to your wish. Note that your input need to be inside form tag.

Comment: did this work if the id come from ajax that i put it on div tag?
sorry for the question, because i'm new with ajax and js

Comment: @Jaromanda X did u get my point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should simply get the data directly in the `hitung2()` function and only pass on the `this` parameter, mainly because you are missing `document` and you have to use `.innerHTML` because that's the way you set it in the first place. Use the function like this:

```
function hitung2(e){
    var txtHint = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML), // parse the string to get the INT value
        banyak = e.value, // this is an input so .value is ok and there's no need to parse it either.
        console.log("txtHint value: "+txtHint); // check on console if values are ok.
        console.log("banyak value: "+banyak); // check on console if values are ok.
        mult = txtHint * banyak; // multiply both INT (if float needed, use parseFloat() in the txtHint variable above)
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = mult; // output it
}
```

This will obviously require you to  use the following HTML instead:

```
<input type='text' id="banyak" name="amount" onkeyup="hitung2(this)" title="Masukkan jumlah" class="tip-right form-control input-sm" required/>
```

**- EDIT -**

Alright, so when you get the price with AJAX from `getprice.php` you are outputting `<input type="text" class="" name="satuan" id="txtHint" value="<?=$price?>" readonly>` which happens to have the same ID (txtHint) as the DIV where it will be nested in. Change this input id to `txtHint-input` so now you can use the following code instead:

```
function hitung2(e){
    var txtHint = document.getElementById("txtHint-input").value,
        banyak = e.value,
        mult = txtHint * banyak;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = mult;
}
```

**- END EDIT -**

Comment: Did you even try to debug it? The result is Nan (Not a Number), try checking with `console.log` what is the value of the variables `textHint` and `banyak`. Once you know that, you'll know why it turns out to be NaN. Maybe you will need to parse `banyak` as well.

Comment: @ObajaLumbanraja oh, and by the way. I assumed it was integer, but if you are going to use float numbers, use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`!!!

Comment: i just try to use `console.log` and this is the result bro,
http://imgur.com/RyKp5rd
seem it's did not return int or float value, seem the problem is from txtHint but i don't know how to start at..

Comment: @ObajaLumbanraja Make sure you return what you want to return. I really have no idea if you are using integers or floats, that is your part of the debugging. But supposing you are using the correct data types, I understand now that whatever it returns is `NaN` for `txtHint`. Did you try with parseFloat()? (Just making sure while I think)...

Comment: OH I know why! You have a doubled `txtHint` ID! When you output the `<input>` with the price from `getprice.php` you are adding an `id="txtHint"` and put it inside a `div` with the exact same ID. So JavaScript can't get it. I will update my answer with what I think is the solution!

Comment: i put the same id inside tag div because it's for show the result that pass from price.js which is txtHint :)

Comment: @ObajaLumbanraja you can't. You just can't have 2 ID's in the same document, only classes. JavaScript doesn't know what to do because ID (identification) is duplicated. Think of it as a person's ID, in the airport... only one person can have a specific number, everyone has different IDs. Change it, I think it's going to solve the issues.

Comment: @ObajaLumbanraja if you really do not want to change it, don't output an `<input>` and simply output the number instead. There's no other way. But of course if you do this, you can't use `.value` because it's a `<div>`, you'd have to use `.innerHTML` to get the number.

Comment: can you help me with the code instead, like the one u help me in the top,

Comment: I did. Look at the answer, I updated. Just use the code in the edit! I did it like an hour ago...

Comment: thank you brother, i just made it work, 
this one work for me, thank you for open my mind about how the ajax work..
`function hitung2(txtHint_input,banyak){
  
    var sum = eval(txtHint_input) * eval(banyak);
    console.log (txtHint_input);
   console.log (banyak);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
};`

Comment: @ObajaLumbanraja Alright! I am very glad it worked, that's all I am here for,  just to help others in the best way I can! Keep using AJAX! It's good! Happy coding!